# Inner-Join PHP Code MySQL

Tags: php, inner-join

I'm trying to do some code that retrieves me the total of inscriptions in my database.
I have a table with the data for the athlets, and another table with the payment information.
But, the problem is when i have a group. If i have a group, 2 or more athlets become a single row in payment table with just the number of the first athlet.

When i try to output the total of inscriptions, a group shows only 1 inscription instead of the real number that could be 2 or more.

At the moment i'm using

```
$result10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atleta 
     INNER JOIN inscricao ON atleta.id_atleta=inscricao.atleta_id_atleta
     WHERE inscricao.parceiro_id_parceiro ='52'");
```

Atleta is the table with the data for athlets. 
Inscricao is the table with the payment info.
parceiro_id_parceiro is the access that i used for the inscription.

Comment: what problem u r facing?

Comment: could you post your tables' structures? [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) would be great.

Comment: I have two important tables in database. The first one is "atleta" with information like: id_atleta, name, group id and other fields that are'n important for this question and in the other table i have the id of inscription, id from athlet, price, etc... the problem is: When i have a athlet for an inscription, its ok. When i have multiplous athlets in the same inscription, it only shows me one inscription. The only field common with the two tables is the "atleta_id_atleta" in inscricao that is "id_atleta" in atleta table.

Comment: Atleta table: https://imageshack.com/i/p8bpLuhwp                       Inscrição table: https://imageshack.com/i/hjS6WfSFp  @Kleskowy

Comment: @Luís Assunção Do you really have 2 or more entires in `inscricao` table with `parceiro_id_parceiro` value of 52? And if so, do you have entries in `atleta` table with corresponding ids to those rows? Your sql seems fine to me and should return more rows, when there are more corresponding entries in both tables. 
If your run this sql in phpMyAdmin, what does it print? Maybe it's not the sql, but the way you access it in PHP.

Comment: @LuísAssunção, images are useless in this case, if you want help, you need to make it easy for someone to reproduce your setup. 99% of the people that could help you, would probably ignore this question instead of trying to understand/copy field names from a picture. Post the output of `show create table atleta`, `show create table inscricao` and some data samples.

Comment: How do you know that an athlete is part of a group ?

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED** try this:

```
$result10 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM atleta where atleta.id_atleta =(select inscricao.atleta_id_atleta from  inscricao  WHERE parceiro_id_parceiro ='52'"));
```

Comment: Stays the same. The problem is that i have the WHERE parceiro_id_parceiro ='52' and parceiro is only of the inscricao table. And it only retrieves the number of groups. @suchit

Comment: better post your table structure.

Comment: Atleta table: imageshack.com/i/p8bpLuhwp Inscrição table: imageshack.com/i/hjS6WfSFp @suchit